# JavaScript: unable to disable/enable an input button

Tags: javascript, django

I'm building a web app using the Django framework.  I'm attempting to use some JavaScript to disable a button that users can press to submit a text-based review.

The JavaScript in the `listing.js` file looks as follows:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    hide_submit_review_button();
});

// Hide the 'Submit Review'button until the user begins typing a review
// Prevent the user from typing more than 100 characters

function hide_submit_review_button() {
    var submit_review_button = document.getElementById('submit-review-button');

    if (submit_review_button !== null) {
        document.getElementById('submit-review-button').disabled = true;

        document.getElementById('review-contents').onkeyup = () => {
            if ((document.getElementById('review-contents').value.length > 0 &&
            document.getElementById('review-contents').value.length <= 100 )) {
                document.getElementById('submit-review-button').disabled = false;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('submit-review-button').disabled = true;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

In my `listing.html` file, I identify the `review-contents` and `submit-review-button`.  Here's the code:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block body %}

    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <form action="{% url 'review' listing.id %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="review" id="review-contents" placeholder="Write a review...">
            <input class="btn btn-primary mt-1" type="submit" id="submit-review-button" value="Submit Review">
        </form>
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        {{ block.super }}
        <script src="{% static 'listing.js' %}"></script>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

An example of a page where the button appears is:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/listings/7

And, here is what the `urls.py` file looks like (if it matters):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('listings/<int:listing_id>', views.listing, name='listing'),
]
```

Can anyone see why this button doesn't disable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resulted from not having the following in the `header` tag in the `layout.html` file:

```
    {% block script %}
    {% endblock %}
```